# AdjustingTable style

Tags: tables

I need to make a table with a specific style, the required style is shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Do the columns have a fixed  width?

Comment: Yes they have, the first and the last have a fixed width  (not like in the image) and the middle columns have a fixed width greater than for the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,  table]{xcolor}%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, tabularx,  booktabs,  hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| >{\columncolor{Lavender!60}}p{2cm}|X|X|X!{\color{Tomato}\vrule width1.2pt} p{2cm}|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Lavender!60} &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \hline
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \arrayrulecolor{Tomato}
    \midrule[1.2pt]
                           &   &   &   &   \\
    \arrayrulecolor{black}\hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is almost the same of what I want except for the `Tomato` color.

Comment: Try `IndianRed4` (`x11names` option of `xcolor`). This option has more than 300 colour names.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.